# Using JMETER, how can I figure out what i'm missing from 2fa request

Tags: jmeter

I have a test in JMETER which has to go through duo 2fa authentication. However the account i'm using is set up to bypass the 2fa, so if I use to log in it just moves me right on through to the app.

But when i'm running my tests in JMETER all the calls to my app after that step fail and show 304: forbidden. Of course i'm using the HTTP Cookie Manager and HTTP Cache Manager. I even pulled the cookies with the regular expression extractor and passed them myself and every single cookie I can see in devtools when I login through a browser is being properly passed- yet i'm still getting 304's.

I can also tell that duo is showing the login as accepted. So I feel like i'm not passing something between duo and the app. But if that's the case it doesn't seem to show up anywhere I can see.

I'm usually doing UI testing so i'm pretty new to JMETER and don't know a ton about how 2FA works behind the scenes. Is there some call i'm missing?

I know this is a bit in the show in the dark, but i'm getting desperate. I just don't see anything missing. The log in is good. Duo accepts it. What could I possibly be missing?

[image]

[image]

My only guess is I found this request in the network tab:
[image]

I do not see any requests for this information in the dashboard call, but I thought maybe the tx parameter needed to be passed down? Truly a guess on my part though.

I'm flailing here.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your login fails due to missing or improperly working [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start).

Record the login twice using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi) and compare resulting test scripts. All the values which differ are a subject to correlation: you need to

1. extract the dynamic value from the previous response using a suitable [JMeter PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. replace recorded hard-coded value with the JMeter Variable from the previous step

Most probably you need to handle this `_xsrf` guy:

[image]

See [What is CSRF & How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-csrf-load-testing) for example challenge and solution.